# I want to know about Is chainlink supports aptos blockchain? If yes then please provide relevant developer docs

Tags: blockchain, move, chainlink, blockchain.info-api, aptos

I want to know about Is chainlink supports aptos blockchain? If yes then please provide relevant developer docs. If not supported then is there any plans adopt aptos blockchain?

Developer resources regarding chainlink support for aptos blockchain. If not please tell us if there any plans to do that or provide till when it will support?

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to ask chainlink and not the whole wide world?

Answer (score 1):

For questions like this, the best approach is to view the documentation for the product in question

https://docs.chain.link/ has all supported chains listed.